# Ubuntu 18.10 stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot, ubuntu-gnome, 18.10

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 two days ago on my laptop which is old one (4 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD). After installing finished, and the first boot it went well. I installed all the necessary software I require like chrome, xampp etc. It was quite smooth but after two days later that means today it just stuck in bootloop (Ubuntu logo which has five white dots and they turn orange, I think it's loading animation) I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Ctr+alt+f1 and it started somehow! I don't know if I have to do this every time. Any permanent solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Comment: The problem still persists. However ctr+shift+f2 can help sometimes. Any permanent solution? I have followed exactly what you said in the above answer.

Comment: Try booting with `nomodeset` in the GRUB kernel line. Screen resolution may be off, but it may give a clue.