# My Ubuntu 18.10 freezes on Boot But my PC is Ok

Tags: boot, 18.10

Today i encountered a problem with my ubuntu 18.10 machine that has proved difficult, at least for me, to tackle so i am asking for help.

Today in the morning i used my pc just fine, but when i came back from work it refused to open and it freezes to some point while booting.

Unfortunately i can only provide an image of the freeze as follows:

[image]

Now, i searched for the last message on the internet but i could only find inquiries about how to cancel the disk checks.

In my case of course that, is not an option since the pc is frozen at this state. I let it run for an hour in hope that it actually was disk checking, but to no avail.

Now, on the same PC i have a second installation of Ubuntu 18.04 which works fine, (plus a windows 10 installation that also works fine), and it is the installation from which i am asking the question.

From my 18.04 system i checked all the disks and they are ok and my whole system is working fine with 18.04

After a few resets it finally booted and the 18.10 system worked fine, until of course i shut it down and when i tried to boot it up it freezes in almost the same point, as you can see in the second picture.

[image]

If i select my Ubuntu 18.04 installation in grub it always starts ok and, keep in mind that both ubuntu systems use the same disks, mounted at the same points.

My PC is a AMD A8 - NVidia GT740 - 16GB RAM - 8 HDDs

I really do not think it is a hardware problem since the system is running fine with 18.04, but the boot freezes completely.

Can anyone think of anything on that ?

P.S. The red vertical line in the pictures is a monitor defect not a vga one.

----- Edit New Info -----

After some reading i disabled all disk checking on boot, but the problem persists although now it does not show the message about the fsck.

Now it freezes on the message about starting the GNOME Display Manager.

What is weird is that many times it boots normally while some other times it does not.

Comment: The answer on this page worked for me. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093510/ubuntu-18-10-stuck-in-bootloop

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my case is different since the computer freezes and i have no ability for recovery/root access etc. I can only reset my machine and reboot.

Comment: Have you checked your disks SMART data to be sure it's not failing? When the disk check runs: does the disk activity light flash, does the drive make any noise? It can take a heck of a long time to check/fix a 2TB drive, say. Are you really using the exact same _partitions_ for 18.04 and 18.10; I can't see how that's even possible. If you boot your 18.04, can you fsck your 18.10 partition(s), eg via gparted, does it give any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but yes i have already, since the beginning actually, thoroughly checked all of my disks and each one of them is ok.

Of course i am not using the same partition for the Ubuntu installations,as you pint out this is impossible, the installations reside on different disks.

The rest of my disks (5) are mounted on the same mount points in each ubuntu installation, so i can actually have identical paths for my files.

Actually i have already gave up on that and i am back using my 18.04 installation permanently. Perhaps i should close this question.