# Stuck in Boot Loop

Tags: boot, apt, lts, motd

I go to boot up my Computer and it's not loading into the GUI.

It takes me directly to:

Login: {username}
Pasword: {pasword}

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS brandon tty1

etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade: 4: lsb_release: not found
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.5.0-44-generic x86_64)

*Documentation https://help.ubuntu.com
*Management: https:///landscape.canonical.com
*Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

606 updates can be installed imemediately.
x of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

*Problem keep persisting, tried autoremove commands, clean etc, apt- list --upgradable and many other commands, I just want to access my GUI, my files are clearly there and pardon me as I am a begineer 'noob' with Ubuntu if this is an easy fix. xD

Answer (score 0):

please [follow the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093510/ubuntu-18-10-stuck-in-bootloop), General the problem lies with the  X-server or initramfs

If that doesn't you can uninstall ,a freshly X-server by droping into cli prompt

> shift + ctrl + alt + f1

It will drop to cli do the necessary changes and reboot the device .

Comment: Not working, now I'm getting E: Unmet dependancies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).